# how to know if a page is deleted by the user? through Facebook Graph API

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I am seeking an answer regarding Facebook Graph API.
How to know if a page is deleted by the user? Can we call some endpoint and see if a new page was added or atleast if the user deletes the page we can make a call and know.
I dont want to call me/accounts and then go through all the pages and then find which one match and which one doesn't and then finally sync my local data.
Thought there might be an easy solution.
Thanks

Comment: No, there is nothing like that.

Comment: ohhh.. that is sad... well,.. thanks

Comment: HI @misorude is it still the same case? No API/webhook to fetch this detail?

Comment: Thankyou for comments guys. appriciate it.